# Objective C NSData equivalent hexadecimal values (iOS) shows negative integer values in JAVA (Android)?

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, encryption

I am working on an application which runs on both iOS and Android platforms. I am totally new to JAVA.
In this app I need to send 32-bytes data as a key from one platform to other.
And this key is used to encrypt/decrypt the actual data.

I am encrypting this 32-bytes key and sending it to other side.

When I print this key (**NSData**) before encrypting at iOS end, I am getting

```
<71c76511 dc0dcb9d c8d3c7b3 4e54b8fe 40fb006f 20f21457 5fbec70d f18c7d52>
```

But when I print the same key (**byte array**), after decryption, at Android end, I am getting

```
 0 = 113  
 1 = -57  
 2 = 101  
 3 = 17  
 4 = -360  
 5 = 13  
 6 = -53  
 7 = -99  
 8 = -56  
 9 = -45  
 10 = -57  
 11 = -77  
 12 = 78  
 13 = 84  
 14 = -72  
 15 = -2  
 16 = 64  
 17 = -5  
 18 = 0  
 19 = 111  
 20 = 32  
 21 = -14  
 22 = 20  
 23 = 87  
 24 = 95  
 25 = -66  
 26 = -57  
 27 = 13  
 28 = -15  
 29 = -116  
 30 = 125  
 31 = 82
```

I can understand that JAVA has byte range of -128 to 127, that’s why it is printing negative values.
I also tried converting both keys to string using **Base64** encoding at both ends, and I got the exact same string.

My questions are

Whether these negative values will cause any harm while decrypting?
If yes, Should I need to cast the negative values to actual hexadecimal values? How?
Or it is just a matter of range and both (**NSData** and **byte array**) are exact same and need not to worry?

Thanks for help in advance :)

---

Right now I am working with encrypting only key and send it to Android.
Now I will work on encryption/decryption of actual data and I don’t want these negative values harm this decryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two are the same. Bytes are just 8-bits and these bits can be represented in many different ways.

NSData displays the data as hexadecimal, Java displays them as signed decimal -128 thru 127.

binary: 01110001
hex: 71
decimal: 113
character: q (not all 8-bit values have a printable character)

binary: 11000111
hex: c7
decimal: -57  (signed byte)
These are just different representations of the same byte value.

Comment: zaph: thanks for writing the answer. I have done with decryption of the actual data using this key, and I get the correct results. That means both the presentations are nothing but the same. Thank you again!